# Convert XML or Json to EDIFACT

Tags: json, xml, xsd, edifact

So i have started to work with conversion from XML or JSON to Edifact (EDI), and i have no idea where to begin. i have started to read a bit about edifact and i thought id post a question here to maybe get some pointers of what is good to know and also maybe of some links and places to start learning about conversion to edifact.

So i have started with trying to convert XML to Edifact and soon realized that i would need an XSD for that. And i thought If Edifact is a pretty tightly kept standard, is there any already existing XSDs for Edifact 911 ORDERS and also DESADV. I couldn't find any.

Any information would be helpful at this moment. Thank you!

Comment: EDIFACT is completely unrelated to XML or JSON so you can't just use a schema or simple transformation to go from one format to another.  The XSD you ask for should be provided by the *creator of the XML file*. You can use it to create classes to read the XML data but *NOT* translate it to a completely unrelated format.

Comment: Furthermore, EDIFACT is anything but a strict standard. Unlike XML, where the XSD completely describes a document, EDIFACT allows organizations to write almost anything they like. Not unlike JSON, only JSON has a simpler format. You have to find the EDIFACT schema and write code that deserializes the XML file and generates an EDIFACT message

Comment: I actually see a lot of things in common between JSON and EDIFACT.
I don't say there can be an exact 1-to-1 map, but achieving such a goal shouldn't be that hard. IMHO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll find any schemas that aren't proprietary to a translation package.  Any schema would probably be a generic representation of the standard, and not specific to your implementation, or your trading partner's guidelines.

Your XML / JSON is proprietary to you (or your ERP).  So you'll need to take the XML tags or JSON objects and convert them into the segment/element enveloped structure of the EDIFACT document.  BOTS might be able to help you here, as it is open source (Python, I think).  Outside of that, there are really great drag/drop mapping tools out there that will allow you to solve your problem.

Comment: Oh, ok, well any ideas of any such drag and drop tools?

Comment: Almost any commercial product nowadays has this.  i'm partial to this product: https://www.liaison.com/products/transform/delta/